# Is it possible to clear the Pager field in AD users & computer using a command?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I need to run though a list of 100 user names and clear their Pager field, can it be done with Power Shell?
The input of the file name which includes the user names looks like this:
itaig
haruth
geloos
fested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want/ can use AD Module than this should be no-brainer:

```
gc cidway.txt | Set-ADUser -Clear pager
```

Read help:

```
Get-Help Set-ADUser -Parameter Clear
```

... for more info.

Comment: Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'ramih                                   ' under: 'DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il'.
At C:\Users\itaig.ASUTA\AppData\Local\Temp\21fb2c52-2bf6-4194-ab99-17713ad6682f.ps1:2 char:30
+ gc c:\cidway.txt | Set-ADUser <<<<  -Clear pager
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ramih                                   :ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'ramih                                   ' under: 'DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manag

Comment: Well, if you have your file wrong (and it looks like it so - mind trailing space) than no command will help you... ;) You can either fix file, or result of gc (e.g. gc | foreach { $_.Trim() } | Set-ADUser

Comment: I've fixed the trailing spaces but receiving the same error:
Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'glasshouseusr' under: 'DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il'.
At line:5 char:30
+ gc c:\cidway.txt | Set-ADUser <<<<  -Clear pager
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (glasshouseusr:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'glasshouseusr' under: 'DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: Error is not the same - it stops on different user now. Unless you've changed txt file it means something is really wrong with this particular user identity. Identity can be DN, sAMAccountName, objectGUID or objectSid (Get-Help Set-ADUser -Parameter Identity). Make sure identities in txt file are correct and match any of attributes that I've mentioned and you are good to go. If you are not sure, just try Get-ADUser <youridentity> and see for yourself. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, i missed your last answer but it solved my issue, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You mean a script?

Something along:

```
Const ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR = 1 
foreach ($usr in Get-Content “C:\file.txt”)
{
Set objUser = GetObject _
   ("LDAP://cn="+$usr", ou=finance, dc=fabrikam, dc=com") 

objUser.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR, "pageNumber", 0
objUser.SetInfo
}
```

Comment: Yes i meant a script in Power Shell, something like this:
Get-Content c:\cidway.txt | foreach-object  { set-aduser -identity $_ -clear pager }

Comment: Well here's a script, if you want a one liner, I can't really help you atm :)

Comment: Can anyone show me how it should be done in Power Shell?

Comment: This is a powershell script...

Comment: but it's not working :(

Comment: It's not PS script. It's VBScript syntax mixed with PS syntax.. ;) So only PS pieces are: foreach ($usr in Get-Content "c:\file.txt") {} everything outside and inside this loop is pure VBScript.

Comment: You are correct, your answer is a lot better anyway :)